# Python - Convert time to different time zone, keep am/pm

Tags: python, datetime

In Python, using this function (takes Eastern Standard Time (EST) with am/pm, should output it in 3 time formats. Central Time (CT), Mountain Time(MT), and Pacific Time(PT) all in the correct am/pm):

```
def time_in_24h(time,time_day): #time is eastern time
''' (number, str)--> number
This function converts a 12-hour time, represented by am/pm,to its equivalent 24-hour time. 
Returns time in the 24-hour format.
'''
cCentral = 'Central Time(CT)' #-1 hour offset
mMountain = 'Mountain Time(MT)'#-2 hours offset
pPacific = 'Pacific Time(PT)'#-3 hours offset
eEst = 'EST is'

if time_day!='pm' and time_day!='am':

    print('Input is not in the right format')  #this is where input is not in the right format
    return 0

else:
    print(time, time_day, eEst, time-1, cCentral)
    print(time, time_day, eEst, time-2, mMountain)
    print(time, time_day, eEst, time-3, pPacific)
```

Using this command:

```
time_in_24h(7,'am')
```

I get this output:

```
7 am EST is 6 Central Time(CT)
7 am EST is 5 Mountain Time(MT)
7 am EST is 4 Pacific Time(PT)
```

I am trying to output the correct 3 times based on the input of EST,am/pm to Central Time (CT), Mountain Time(MT), and Pacific Time(PT) all in the correct am/pm. How can I get the correct am/pm outputted based on the offsets? For example, 2pm EST input, should output:

```
1 pm EST is 12 pm Central Time(CT)
1 pm EST is 11 am Mountain Time(MT)
1 pm EST is 10 am Pacific Time(PT)
```

As you see, pm/am change based on the offsets and it is not consistent. What would be the best way to handle this as it varies based on the time (am/pm)? Anything built in python already to handle this without an issue? Any solution to my dilemma? I gave it my all and really stuck on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Central, just check if the Eastern time is 12 pm. If it is, then adjust to 11 am. Similarly, if eastern is midnight, then adjust to (11) pm. It'll take a bit of `if`s, but you could do it.

The problem is, **it's still wrong**. Date-time math is hard, and you've forgotten about DST.

Typically, once a year, it's 1 AM in Eastern time (EST), but also 1 AM in Central time (CDT). (Likewise, it's also once 3 AM in Eastern, and 1 AM in Central.)

You can't, with the amount of inputs your function currently takes, account for this: you need to know the full date and time. Once you do, it's easiest to just convert that full Eastern (America/New_York) date and time to UTC, and then convert that to Central (America/Chicago), Mountain (America/Denver) and Pacific (America/Los_Angeles).

The America/… bits are the names for the timezones that the TZ database on most machines uses. America/New_York is the "Eastern" time: it specifies when DST is, when it isn't, and what the offset from UTC is. It even has historical data, as the dates when DST starts & end have changed. (And on a global scale, actually change quite often. Governments…)

### Keeping the non-DST aware version:

First, let's get two helper functions going: `to_24hour`, which converts a `(hour, ampm)` to a 24-hour format, and `to_12hour`, which goes the other way. These will make things easier to think about, as we can do the subtractions a lot more easily in 24-hour time.

```
def to_24hour(hour, ampm):
    """Convert a 12-hour time and "am" or "pm" to a 24-hour value."""
    if ampm == 'am':
        return 0 if hour == 12 else hour
    else:
        return 12 if hour == 12 else hour + 12

def to_12hour(hour):
    """Convert a 24-hour clock value to a 12-hour one."""
    if hour == 0:
        return (12, 'am')
    elif hour < 12:
        return (hour, 'am')
    elif hour == 12:
        return (12, 'pm')
    else:
        return (hour - 12, 'pm')
```

Once we have those, things get simpler:

```
def time_in_24h(time,time_day): #time is eastern time
    ''' (number, str)--> number
    This function converts a 12-hour time, represented by am/pm,to its equivalent 24-hour time. 
    Returns time in the 24-hour format.
    '''
    cCentral = 'Central Time(CT)' #-1 hour offset
    mMountain = 'Mountain Time(MT)'#-2 hours offset
    pPacific = 'Pacific Time(PT)'#-3 hours offset
    eEst = 'EST is'

    if time_day!='pm' and time_day!='am':

        print('Input is not in the right format')  #this is where input is not in the right format
        return 0

    else:
        est_24hour = to_24hour(time, time_day)
        hour, ampm = to_12hour((est_24hour - 1 + 24) % 24)
        print(time, time_day, eEst, hour, ampm, cCentral)
        hour, ampm = to_12hour((est_24hour - 2 + 24) % 24)
        print(time, time_day, eEst, hour, ampm, mMountain)
        hour, ampm = to_12hour((est_24hour - 3 + 24) % 24)
        print(time, time_day, eEst, hour, ampm, pPacific)
```

… with those adjustments:

```
>>> time_in_24h(1, 'pm')
1 pm EST is 12 pm Central Time(CT)
1 pm EST is 11 am Mountain Time(MT)
1 pm EST is 10 am Pacific Time(PT)
```

One last note. Your docstring reads:

> (number, str)--> number
>
> This function converts a 12-hour time, represented by am/pm,to its equivalent 24-hour time.
>
> Returns time in the 24-hour format.

This, of course, is what `to_24hour` does.

### With timezone awareness

Python doesn't really help with timezones; Justin Barber, in a separate answer, suggests `pytz`; it's a good choice.

If we have some date or time that we know to be in Eastern:

```
now = datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 14, 12, 34)
```

Grab the timezones:

```
et = pytz.timezone('America/New_York')
ct = pytz.timezone('America/Chicago')
mt = pytz.timezone('America/Denver')
pt = pytz.timezone('America/Los_Angeles')
```

We can convert to Central and the others with:

```
now_et = et.normalize(et.localize(now))
now_ct = ct.normalize(now_et.astimezone(ct))
now_mt = mt.normalize(now_et.astimezone(mt))
now_pt = pt.normalize(now_et.astimezone(pt))
```

(As a comment notes, `pytz` oddly requires a call to `normalize` when a change might cross a DST boundary, which is basically anything you do.)

Then:

```
print('{} Eastern in various other timezones:'.format(now_et.strftime('%I %p')))
print('Central : {}'.format(now_ct.strftime('%I %p')))
print('Mountain: {}'.format(now_mt.strftime('%I %p')))
print('Pacific : {}'.format(now_pt.strftime('%I %p')))
```

Comment: Thanks Thanatos. Without any of the complexities though, (I am new to this so does not need to be 100%, just take into consideration the offsets am/pm) any pseudo code you can provide?

Comment: 1. It is incorrect to use `datetime.now()`, use `datetime.now(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))` instead. 2. You might need `.normalize()` calls: now_ct = ct_tz.normalize(now_et.astimezone(ct_tz))` 3. Do not encourage a newbie to create kitchen-sink functions. The code doesn't correspond to the docstring. `time_in_24h()` could be split into a couple of functions. 4. Do not hardcode timezone rules in the code (1,2,3 hour offsets between the timezones in your code), use a timezone database instead such as one provided by `pytz` module.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian 1. The `now` call starts off with a naive datetime object, it adds TZ info with the call to `localize`: could you explain what difference passing the TZ to `now` would make? 2. Similarly, what does `normalize` do? 3. Could you expound of "kitchen-sink functions"? I've attempted to encourage him to break out his code: see `to_24hour` and `to_12hour`. 4. "Use a [TZ database] [such as] `pytz`": The answer uses `pytz`!

Comment: @Thanatos: 1. do you think `datetime.now()` returns the same result on your machine and mine? How about `datetime.now(tz)`? (assume the clocks are in sync but timezone may be different) 2. pytz docs shows why you might need `.normalize()`: read them (it is a single page) 3. "kitchen-sink" means that function named `time_in_24h` should not try to do too much, look at how the work is divided in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22437027/4279) 4. Does `time_in_24h()` function in your answer that has hardcoded offsets (1,2,3)  use `pytz`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: 1. No, of course not. `datetime.now` was just an example input time. I've changed it to a hard-coded constant. 2. That the docs are a single page is not an indication of shortness. In particular, pytz lacks a reference. 3. `time_in_24h` is the OP's function, not mine. I've attempted to answer his question, not completely refactor his question. As it is, I've already addressed this at the end of the answer.

Comment: 4. You're stubbornly ignoring the header on that answer that in large print reads "non-DST aware version", and where the OP remarked "Without any of the complexities" "it does not need to be 100%". I provided the very simple fix the OP asked for, noted where it fell down, *and* provided him the start of some code that would avoid all the problems in his original method. So no, the top half doesn't use `pytz` because by definition it cannot.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about timezones then you must specify a date (year, month, day) in addition to the time.

To convert given `hours` and `am_or_pm` to a different timezone:

1. convert to 24 hours
2. add date
3. create timezone-aware datetime object in the source timezone
4. convert it to the given timezones

`time_in_24h` shouldn't try to do too much. Let it do what its name implies, namely: convert input hours, am or pm to 24 hours format:

```
def time_in_24h(hours, am_or_pm):
    """Convert to 24 hours."""
    if not (1 <= hours <= 12):
        raise ValueError("hours must be in 01,..,12 range, got %r" % (hours,))
    hours %= 12 # accept 12am as 00, and 12pm as 12
    am_or_pm = am_or_pm.lower()
    if am_or_pm == 'am':
        pass
    elif am_or_pm == 'pm':
        hours += 12
    else:
        raise ValueError("am_or_pm must be 'am' or 'pm', got: %r" % (am_or_pm,))
    return hours
```

You could also implement it using `strptime()`:

```
from datetime import datetime

def time_in_24h(hours, am_or_pm):
    return datetime.strptime("%02d%s" % (hours, am_or_pm), '%I%p').hour
```

Then you could define `print_times()` function that prints times in the 3 different timezones:

```
from datetime import datetime, time
import pytz

def astimezone(aware_dt, dest_tz):
    """Convert the time to `dest_tz` timezone"""
    return dest_tz.normalize(aware_dt.astimezone(dest_tz))

def print_times(hours, am_or_pm, date=None, is_dst=None):
    source_tz = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')

    # 2. add date
    if date is None: # if date is not specified; use today
        date = datetime.now(source_tz).date()
    naive_dt = datetime.combine(date, time(time_in_24h(hours, am_or_pm), 0, 0))

    # 3. create timezone-aware datetime object in the source timezone
    source_dt = source_tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=is_dst)

    #NOTE: these timezone names are deprecated,
    #      use Continent/City format instead
    fmt = '%I %p %Z'
    for tzname in 'US/Central', 'US/Mountain', 'US/Pacific':
        dest_dt = astimezone(source_dt, pytz.timezone(tzname))
        print("{source_dt:{fmt}} is {dest_dt:{fmt}} ({tzname})".format(
            **locals()))
```

It is important to specify the date correctly, otherwise you won't know the correct UTC offset. The code uses `pytz` module to access timezone information. [`strftime()` format codes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) are used for printing.

Example:

```
>>> print_times(7, 'am')
07 AM EDT is 06 AM CDT (US/Central)
07 AM EDT is 05 AM MDT (US/Mountain)
07 AM EDT is 04 AM PDT (US/Pacific)
>>> print_times(1, 'pm')
01 PM EDT is 12 PM CDT (US/Central)
01 PM EDT is 11 AM MDT (US/Mountain)
01 PM EDT is 10 AM PDT (US/Pacific)
>>> print_times(9, 'pm')
09 PM EDT is 08 PM CDT (US/Central)
09 PM EDT is 07 PM MDT (US/Mountain)
09 PM EDT is 06 PM PDT (US/Pacific)
```

Special note:

- `datetime.now(source_tz)` allows to get the correct current time in the given timezone. `datetime.now()` would be incorrect here if the local timezone is not `source_tz`
- `is_dst=None` means that `tz.localize()` method raises an exception for ambiguous or non-existing local times. Otherwise it just defaults to `is_dst=False` that might not be what you want
- `tz.normalize()` might be necessary if the conversion happens across DST boundary

Answer (score 1):

You might try `pytz`. You can install it with `pip install pytz`. There you can do something like this with the `normalize` method (based on [the docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> import pytz
>>> central = timezone('US/Central')
>>> mountain = timezone('US/Mountain')
>>> mountain_date = mountain.localize(datetime.now())  # set time as right now mountain time
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p'
>>> central_date = central.normalize(mountain_date.astimezone(central))
>>> print central_date.strftime(fmt), central, 'is', mountain_date.strftime(fmt), mountain
2014-03-15 07:29:17 PM US/Mountain is 2014-03-15 08:29:17 PM US/Central
```

So your function might end up looking something like this:

```
>>> def time_in_24h(hour, am_pm):
    """hour is an integer that represents eastern time on the 12-hour clock, and am_pm
       will take any string that begins with 'a' or 'p'"""
    if not am_pm.lower().startswith(('a', 'p')):  # return None if am_pm does not start with 'a' or 'p'
        return
    central = timezone('US/Central')
    mountain = timezone('US/Mountain')
    pacific = timezone('US/Pacific')
    eastern = timezone('US/Eastern')
    if hour == 12:
        mod_hour = 0 if am_pm.lower().startswith('a') else 12
    else:
        mod_hour = hour + 12 if am_pm.lower().startswith('p') else hour  # add 12 if am_pm starts with 'p', but keep original hour for display purposes
    fmt = '%H:%M %p'
    eastern_time = eastern.localize(datetime(1900, 1, 2, mod_hour))
    for tz in (central, mountain, pacific):
        d = tz.normalize(eastern_time.astimezone(tz))
        print hour, am_pm, 'EST is', d.strftime(fmt), tz  # tz displays as pytz timezone; can change


>>> time_in_24h(1, 'am')
1 am EST is 00:00 AM US/Central
1 am EST is 23:00 PM US/Mountain
1 am EST is 22:00 PM US/Pacific
>>> time_in_24h(9, 'pm')
9 pm EST is 20:00 PM US/Central
9 pm EST is 19:00 PM US/Mountain
9 pm EST is 18:00 PM US/Pacific
```

Comment: hmmm.. I am still new to Python but I need to use the time_in_24h() function that I posted. How can I integrate that to get the correct output I posted from the input?

Comment: @Maverick I integrated this technique into your original function (and improved the function in some small ways). See the modified answer above. You can further modify as necessary.

Comment: your function fails for `12am` and `12pm` it should be 00:00 and 12:00 in 24h correspondingly. There are two implementations of the conversion in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22437027/4279)

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Thanks, I corrected the code. +1 for your answer.

Comment: today is probably a better default if the explicit date is not given than `1900/1/2` in your code. `.localize()` might return wrong answer for ambiguous times; `is_dst` could be used to resolve ambiguity. [Point 3 from this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432030/python-convert-time-to-different-time-zone-with-am-pm/22437027#comment34121849_22432116) also applies to your answer.