# Convert django default datetime format into am,pm in django/tenjin template

Tags: django-models, django-templates

How can I convert django datetime field to the format that shows in the django/tenjin template. Date time field in database is '00:01:00', I want to show 12:01 a.m in my tenjin/django template .Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Convert time to different time zone with am/pm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432030/python-convert-time-to-different-time-zone-with-am-pm)

Comment: In django template we can do like this..... {{ default_time_value | time: "%I:%M %p" }} or {{date_time_value |time:"P"}}

Comment: In tenjin template we can do like this..... ${ default_time_value.strftime("%I:%M %p" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for django template- {{ default_time_value | time: "%I:%M %p" }} or {{default_time_value |time:"P"}}

for tenjin template- ${ my_time.strftime("%I:%M %p") }

Answer (score 1):

Use Django's [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date) filter:

```
{{ my_date|date:"h:i a" }}
```

Comment: i got the answer using ${ my_time.strftime("%I:%M %p" }